# Using MySQL Connector/NET with NHibernate web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, nhibernate, driver

I have an IIS server with MySQL Connector/NET version 6.2.3 installed on it. I'm using NHibernate, and I'm not entirely sure how to set up my web application to use this driver. Am I correct in saying that I can use any version of the .NET connector so long as it's referenced by the application? If so, where/how do I reference the driver in Web.config?

I initially was using version 6.3.6, which had an installer and didn't require me to add any references in my project. However, upon deploying to the server, I discovered that the version installed there was 6.2.3, which gave this error:

`Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Just needed to set `providerName` to `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` in `connectionStrings`.